# QOS python code for create_subscriber

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I have tried various code snippets but have not been able to create correct code for sensor QOS definition for a service
I am writing in python

```
    self.speed_subscription = self.create_subscription(
        Int32,
        'distance',
        self.speed_listener_callback,1)
        # self.listener_callback,rmw_qos_profile_sensor_data)
```

So I like to replace the 1 with sensor profile for QOS

Any hints is appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360676/qos-python-code-for-create_subscriber/) by [maxbback](https://answers.ros.org/users/58851/maxbback/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-08-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
from rclpy import qos
self.speed_subscription = self.create_subscription(
    Int32,
    'distance',
    self.speed_listener_callback,qos.qos_profile_sensor_data)
```

---

Originally posted by [doronhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/45360/doronhi/) with karma: 31 on 2021-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've pull this from my code I use to get images from the RS camera (which requires a non-default QoS policy).

```
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.qos import QoSProfile, QoSReliabilityPolicy, QoSHistoryPolicy

class MyNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        qos_profile = QoSProfile(
            reliability=QoSReliabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT,
            history=QoSHistoryPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_KEEP_LAST,
            depth=1
        )

        sub = Subscriber(
            self,
            Image,
            "rgb_img",
            qos_profile=qos_profile
        )
        sub.registerCallback(self._on_rgb)

    def _on_rgb(self, msg):
        ...
```

---

Originally posted by [SmallJoeMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56482/smalljoeman/) with karma: 116 on 2021-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3